# Applying an existentially typed function to a sufficiently polymorphic argument

Tags: haskell, existential-type

Suppose I have a very simple way of generating a stream from a state transition function:

```
machine :: (s -> s) -> (s -> a) -> s -> [a]
machine next proj s0 = proj <$> iterate next s0
```

At some point, I'd like to use that function without caring about the exact choice of `s`. Let's say I have a type for my state that has a type parameter:

```
data Foo a = Foo1 Int | Foo2 a
```

and I have a state transition function that has some `a` in mind:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Step = forall a. MkStep (Foo a -> Foo a)

step :: Step
step = _
```

I am careful to observe my state in a type parameter-agnostic way:

```
observe :: forall a. Foo a -> Int
observe (Foo1 x) = x
observe _ = 0
```

My initial state is also type parameter-agnostic:

```
initial :: forall a. Foo a
initial = Foo1 0
```

Given all these favorable conditions, I have hoped that I can package up the `initial` state, the transition `step` and the `observe`ation since both `initial` and `observe` can be instantiated to match the `step` function's choice of `a`, but no dice:

```
test :: [Int]
test = let MkStep next = step in machine next observe initial
```

> ````
>     • Couldn't match expected type ‘p’
>                   with actual type ‘Foo a -> Foo a’
>         because type variable ‘a’ would escape its scope
>       This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
>         a pattern with constructor:
>           MkStep :: forall a. (Foo a -> Foo a) -> Step,
>         in a pattern binding
>         at StateMachine.hs:21:12-22
>     • In the pattern: MkStep next
>       In a pattern binding: MkStep next = step
>       In the expression:
>         let MkStep next = step in machine next observe initial ```
> ````

Is there a way to achieve this, without changing the type of `machine`?[1]

Interestingly, consuming the `Step` as a parameter works:

```
test2 :: Step -> [Int]
test2 (MkStep next) = machine next observe initial
```

But I'd rather not rewrite my code along this direction.

[1] Here I am using lists, but for my real use case, `machine` is a Clash signal combinator from the standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
test :: [Int]
test = case step of
   MkStep next -> machine next observe initial
   -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ case instead of let
```

Essentially, you have to use `case` or another form of "strict" pattern matching to bring the existential type in scope. A biding introduced by `let` is lazy and won't do that.